# using Dropzone to convert image to base64

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dropzone

I'm using dropzone and nuxtjs, I implemented on top of Dropzone that provides drag and drop functionality for file uploads with image previews, this  is my code

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-dropzone id="drop1" :options="dropOptions"></vue-dropzone>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vueDropzone from "vue2-dropzone";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    dropOptions: {
      url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
      maxFilesize: 2, // MB
      maxFiles: 4,
      chunking: true,
      chunkSize: 500, // bytes
      thumbnailWidth: 150, // px
      thumbnailHeight: 150,
      addRemoveLinks: true
    }
  }),
  components: {
    vueDropzone
  },
  methods: {
    removeAllFiles() {
      this.$refs.dropzone.removeAllFiles();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm just trying to convert image to base64 and then save it in database, what can I do it?

Comment: Base64 is for smaller images no? And it should be done on the server for performance reasons IMO.

Comment: oh good point! in that case, I should send the original image??

Comment: Yeah, if it's not too big, just send it there. Then compress it (if needed) and encode it if needed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.